# Peeking into MSMQ Before Committing and Receiving

Tags: oracle, transactions, msmq

For my C# .Net MSMQ application (using System.Messaging), I'd like to perform an insert into an oracle db as a transaction.  The queue I will be reading from is a local private queue that another service will write to.

I was thinking of using the Peek method to first grab and insert the data.  If no exceptions or problems occur with the db insert, then I'd call Receive to remove the message from the queue.

I know that there is the TransactionScope feature, but are there any downsides to performing my operation as described above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are. Someone else can theoretically grab that message while you are doing your database insert. The preferred method is to use two separate transactions where one is used to receive the message and the other for your database call (if needed). And if the database call fails you will rollback the receive transaction.

So in pseudo code it will look like this:

```
Initiate receive transaction

    Receive message // Message will not be displayed in the queue, but it is still there

    Initiate DB transaction

        Insert data

        Commit DB transaction  // Message will be removed from the queue

    Commit receive transaction

Catch exception

    Rollback DB transaction

    Rollback receive transaction  // Message will be visible in the queue again
```

I would not recommend that you use the same transaction for both actions as there can be some sideeffects then and you will not be in full control of the workflow.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'm looking into implementing this.  However, for information purposes, if I have full control over the local queue, and will be only implementing one single threaded receiver, so that no one else would be able to grab my message while I'm doing the db insert, do you think that this method described above would still be preferred?

Comment: Of course you could implement it using peek and then receive after db insert, but if you use my proposed pattern you would have a more durable solution which could easily be reused in other scenarios and also be more correct from a architectural standpoint.

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2007/12/11/how-do-i-get-transactional-remote-receives.aspx

Comment: This will be a local (private) queue, I will update my question to clarify this point.

Comment: Same principle for local queues.